# Vue Render HTML - You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-tables-2

I'm trying to render HTML dynamically in Vue (javascript) and I'm getting this error, does anyone know how to fix it?

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (224:36)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js
 * ./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
```

This is the code that generates the above error:

```
    headings: {
       id: 'ID',
       selected: function (h) {
          return  <b-form-checkbox v-model={this.checkedAll} onChange={this.selectAll}>
                </b-form-checkbox>
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by installing babel

https://github.com/vuejs/babel-plugin-transform-vue-jsx

babel.config.js

```
    module.exports = {
     presets: [
      '@vue/app'
     ]
    }
```