# Ionic Vue failed to compile

Tags: vue.js, ionic-framework, ionic4

I was running ionic serve in local computer and got following error

[compilation error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/23D6h.png)

It was working fine earlier, also I didn't make any changes to code whatsoever. I don't understand what is causing this error.

I tried following

1. Freshly clone project from git repo
2. Re-install npm dependencies
3. Un-install and re-install ionic globally

None of the above methods worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this bug,

One of the components contained lang typescript where as ionic system is using javascript.

SignIn Component:

```
<script lang="ts">
//logic
</script>
```

I just removed lang and ionic compiled files properly.

Earlier versions didn't track this error.I recently upgraded ionic version to 6.17.1.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the error log, which say:

```
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
```

You need to add vue-loader to your webpack configuration. You can find an example of such an integration here:
https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack-simple

Someone said here ["You may need an appropiate loader to handle this file type" webpack and vue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45031720/you-may-need-an-appropiate-loader-to-handle-this-file-type-webpack-and-vue) that he solved the problem by downgrading vue-loader using:

```
npm install vue-loader@14 --save-dev.
```

Apparently v15 has some issues.

I suggest you to look in this posts:

- [Error: "You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62738146/error-you-may-need-an-additional-loader-to-handle-the-result-of-these-loaders)
- ["You may need an appropiate loader to handle this file type" webpack and vue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45031720/you-may-need-an-appropiate-loader-to-handle-this-file-type-webpack-and-vue)
- [Vue Render HTML - You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59989616/vue-render-html-you-may-need-an-additional-loader-to-handle-the-result-of-thes)
- [Vue - You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58139787/vue-you-may-need-an-additional-loader-to-handle-the-result-of-these-loaders)